# Why is my Smooth tool causing the surface of my sculpt to be reflective?

Tags: rendering, sculpting

While sculpting something - inexplicably after I boolean joined two meshes - the newly joined mesh has an issue where the smooth tool will cause the normals to become reflective!

I've tried recalculating surface normals to no effect. What the butt is going on?

[image: Big ol shiny spot!]

Comment: There is no reflection. (Blenders viewport isn't able to show reflections.) Instead you see the back faces from the inner side. What you see is a hole.

Comment: That's what i initally thought, but when i rotate the viewport the faces are in fact the surface. If i use the draw sculpt tool, the geometry raises and the color shifts.I can select the faces in edit mode as well.

Comment: feel free to share the .blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is actually the Solidify modifier. When i applied the mirror I was under the impression that i needed to use solidify to make the mirrored geometry physical.

Solidify will make an internal geometry. when sculpting, i would only be hitting the upper mesh and it would clip through the lower.

Lesson learned: do NOT solidify objects you intend to add to a sculpt.

Comment: More correctly: Do not solidify objects at all unless your model requires solidification (e.g. a non-manifold mesh).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the normals flipped. Press space to search, then type normals and find 'flip normals' or try pressing ctrl + N.

The normal is just the direction of the surface. In 3D, surfaces usually face 1 direction unless you flag that particular face or group of faces to face another direction or have a renderable face on either side.